# How to retrieve object value from JSON in Quartz Job Scheduler

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I have a json in the below format which i get it from the front end:

json values:
     [book:[name:Java,author:Test], id:1]

When i am trying to retrieve those values in schedulerService using Quartz Job scheduler i dont see those values.Below is the code:

```
//job controller

try{
   JobDetail job = new JobDetail(request.JSON);
   println request.JSON     //i dont see the JSON values
   def id = context.mergedJobDataMap.get('id');
 }
```

Comment: If you `println request.JSON` before `new JobDetail(request.JSON)` are the values there?

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Its grails 3.1.9

Comment: When i println context.mergedJobDataMap i see the value as org.grails.plugins.quartz.grailsJobName:test.job.If i get only one value in JSON like json values: [ id:1] then i am able to see the value.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what the problem is.  If you are passing `[book:[name:Java,author:Test], id:1]` as a constructor argument to `JobDetail`, I wouldn't expect that to do anything useful unless `JobDetail` has a `book` property in it.